# How to write getInstance method thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a `getInstance` method in my library which is being used in multiple threads but I am not sure whether it is thread safe:

```
protected static DataClient instance;

protected DataClient() {
    // do stuff here
}

public static synchronized void initialize() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DataClient();
    }
}

public static DataClient getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        initialize();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

And this is the way I am using it:

```
DataClient.getInstance();
```

Is this thread safe and if not then can anyone explain why it is not thread safe?

Comment: You asked and deleted this question earlier.  Had I not wasted effort on an answer to the earlier question then I might have been more inclined to write an answer this iteration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this thread safe and if not then can anyone explain why it is not thread safe?

It is not thread safe because you are in effect doing the [double check locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) error.  There is nothing to protect the `instance` from being published *before* it is fully instantiated.  Just because `initialize()` is `synchronized` doesn't mean that it won't publish `instance` before the end of the synchronized block which can be seen in the non-synchronized `getInstance()` method.  So a thread calling `getInstance()` might get a reference to a partially initialized `DataClient` instance.

In additional, even if the creating thread publishes it, there is nothing that guarantees that another thread will update the memory associated with the object.  Cached memory can cause partial objects and other critical memory issues.

Here are some ways to make it safe:

- Easiest way is to make `instance` be `volatile`.  This forces a write memory barrier to be crossed when `instance` is written and a read memory barrier to be crossed when it is accessed.  That fixes the double-check-locking bug.
- You can instantiate the object upon class load which is done synchronously:

  ```
  protected static final DataClient instance = new DataClient();
  ```
- You could use an `AtomicReference` but that just wraps a `volatile` object so making `instance` `volatile` is similar.
- You could make sure that all of the fields in `DataClient` are `final` or `volatile` so that the object would be fully constructed when the constructor finishes.  Although still a bad pattern, I believe that this stops the memory model from being able to reorder constructor initialization *after* the object is constructed.  For more [read this page](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/all-fields-are-final/).

For example, let's say you have 2 threads.  Thread1 calls `getInstance()` with `instance` being `null`.  It calls `initialize()` which constructs the `DataClient` and publishes it to the `static` `instance` variable.  It then reaches the end of the `synchronized` block so `instance` is published to central memory.

Thread2 now calls `getInstance()` and gets a reference to `instance` but has some of the parts of `instance` memory cached which is now out of date.  Because it does not cross a read memory barrier, there is no mechanism for Thread2 to be forced to update its memory cache to ensure that `instance` has been properly shared.  It might see `instance` with only some or none of the fields updated.  Memory synchronization has to be applied by *both* the publisher and the consumer threads otherwise memory race conditions can occur.

---

Answer (score -4):

It should be, isn't the general idea of having something be "thread safe" also be guaranteed of [Race Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing)? If so, I don't think this would be an issue when calling it that it could mess up your sequencing for other code.

EDIT: Basically, since you are only reading the instance, it shouldn't be an issue as you aren't also doing other actions to the instance in side of this method.

Comment: Two threads can at the same time see `if (instance == null)` and then init the instance. That's typically considered unsafe because one of those threads will end up with the wrong instance.

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Oh, there is a synchronized so it's not what I though but the good old [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) explains the ugly details why it can still fail.