# Writing thread safe singleton class

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I wrote a below Singleton class. I am not sure whether this is thread safe singleton class or not?

```
protected static DataTask instance;

protected DataTask() {
    // some code here
}

public static synchronized void setup() {
    if (instance == null) {
        DataTask setupFully = new DataTask();
        instance = setupFully;
    }
}

public static DataTask getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        setup();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Prefer enum with single constant as `INSTANCE`, I feel that is the best way.

Comment: You are using the DCL idiom without `volatile` so no, it is not.

Comment: Does it always have to be enum. Why cannot we write thread safe class without enum? I don't want to use enum.

Comment: @rajuGT that's not lazy. Which might be important to the OP. But I completely agree with you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you explain why it is not thread safe with some threads example just for understanding? I thought in my setup method inside if instance null check that will make thread safe? I mean this line `DataTask setupFully = new DataTask();
        instance = setupFully;`

Comment: `enum` is used because it provides a huge number of guarantees. For example with any other approach, serialization can be used to bypass the single instance. An `enum` guarantees that even when deserialized there will still be only one instance.

Comment: Thread safety is not a 5 minute Stackoverflow question. It requires a lot of careful study. But I assure you, this is not threadsafe.

Comment: Why do you use `protected` instead of `private`? Access to constructor should be limited to only singleton class so `protected` can't be used here.

Comment: Re. "careful study" OP please purchase *[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)* by Brian Goetz.  It's the best book there is on Java thread safety.

Comment: I feel like Gray has already explained all this in [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184749/how-to-write-getinstance-method-thread-safe). What do you think is missing? Why are you still confused? Explain why you think it'd be thread safe or why you think it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is double-checked locking.  It does not work because there is no guarantee in the unsynchronized method when the instance variable is set.  This guarantee can be enforced by making instance `volatile`.  There are many articles on double-checked locking including [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking)